# setting font family in font (ignoring size)

Tags: objective-c, ios6, fonts, font-family

What I was trying is set font size and font family separately due to some reasons.

For setting size I used

```
[addressLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
```

However for family name I am not finding how to do that.. Any idea how to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than just the font family, you need the font name. Once you have a font name, if you want to update the label's font to the new font with the same size, you can do:

```
UIFont *oldFont = addressLabel.font
UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithName:someName size:oldFont.pointSize];
addressLabel.font = newFont;
```